# How does this supply network for Vcc work?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, ltspice, mosfet-driver, power-factor-correction

The following schematic refers to a PFC driven by L6562A.

What is the current flow in the supply network of this IC in the two different statuses of MOSFET=ON and MOSFET=OFF?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R4 and R5 apply a limited supply to the chip during the power-up-from-cold scenario. Once operating, the chip receives sufficient power from the secondary winding of the main inductor (named T1). So, now R4 and R5 can be forgotten about.

What you are left with is the secondary winding of T1 producing an AC voltage (due to MOSFET Q1 switching). That secondary AC voltage is of course used by the ZCD pin for timing reasons but, it is also shunt rectified and regulated by D2 (an 18 volt zener diode). This produces a fairly stable DC voltage that is passed to the main smoothing capacitors (C4 and C29) via diode D8.

C5 blocks DC from across zener diode D2 as per this diagram from [this diode-clamper site](https://www.theengineeringknowledge.com/diode-clamper-circuits/): -

[image]

And, because D2 is a zener diode it clamps the top of the waveform (above) to about 18 volts and, to prevent excessive current flow into D2 during peak clamping, R14 is used.

Comment: thanks andy aka. and what are C5 and R14 for?

Comment: @Kamran additions made to answer.